# Prevent Accidental Deletion of AWS S3 Buckets

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

On initiating service instance deletion call, Object Store service ensures deletion of service instance resources, which includes AWS S3 bucket(s), and hence the objects in the bucket also gets deleted. Since there is no backup or a backup is very costly, is there any way where I can avoid this accidental deletion of important data?

Answer (score 0):

We can use the parameter 'preventDeletion' which if enable wont let you delete a file